# Close JDBC connections after a set timeout period?

Tags: java, jdbc, connection, connection-pooling, connection-timeout

Is there a way to close JDBC connections after a set timeout period?  These connections are being created in a GenericObjectPool.  I know the pool can close idle connections in the pool, but what about connections that are thought to be active?  I am trying to control connections leaks in the event someone doesn’t call close().  From what I have read the only way may be to set a timeout period on the server, but I am hoping to find a way in Java.  Thank you!

Comment: I would make sure you close your resources correctly. Trying to work around the problem can hide more serious issues.

Comment: Can you elaborate some on this: "in the event someone doesn’t call close()."

Comment: I think he means that the programmer has forgotten to call `close()` on the connection.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Peter Lawrey that I would make sure to close the connection always. But if I still have to ensure that a connection is closed (if someone took it from the pool and forgot to return it), I would do it as follows:

1. Decorate the java.sql.Connection that is returned by the pool.
2. Create a timer in the constructor and set it to duration configured, to tolerate with active connections.
3. If the user calls close on it before the timer fires, I will cancel the timer and return the connection to the pool.
4. If the timer fires before the connection is closed by the user, I will return the connection to the pool and invalidate the decorated connection so that further calls will throw `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: Just to mention that in `Glassfish` there is a `Leak Timeout` and `Leak Reclaim` connection pool advanced settings. If a connection is not returned to the pool after `Leak Timeout` seconds, then it is automatically returned to the pool(if `Leak Reclaim` is enabled).

Comment: Yeah, activeConnectionTimeout has become a coomon configurable parameter in connection poolers. Thanks for the info about glassfish

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I'll look into this.  You guys are right, calling close is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the old Apache commons pool, but I switched over to the new Apache [Tomcat Pool](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html)  This actually has a feature to remove connections after a timeout period.

removeAbandoned - (boolean) Flag to remove abandoned connections if they exceed the removeAbandonedTimout. If set to true a connection is considered abandoned and eligible for removal if it has been in use longer than the removeAbandonedTimeout Setting this to true can recover db connections from applications that fail to close a connection. See also logAbandoned The default value is false.